# Jersey Resource Constructor Variable Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Resource class where almost all methods accept a variable of Foo type as parameter. At the start of every request I need to work on this object. Is there a way I can move all of this into the constructor of the resource:

```
public class Resource{

   public Resource(Foo foo){
         // common lines of code
   }

   @POST
   public methodOne(Foo foo){

   }

}
```

I get dependency errors If I try this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use dependency injection to inject Foo. JEE6 has DI support with JSR330.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the common code to a separate method and then call that method from each request method:

```
...
private Foo processFoo(Foo foo)
{
    Foo newFoo;
    // common processing here
    return newFoo;
}

@POST
public methodOne(Foo foo){
    Foo processedFoo = processFoo(foo);
    ...
}
...
```